# Puppet ensure apt-get update before MySQL

Tags: mysql, puppet, vagrant

Am using the Puppet module from https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-mysql and for some reason it keeps producing errors regarding apt-get update.

The exact error message can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/4600183).

For some strange reason the MySQL class is being executed first before anything else and before my apt-get update command executes.

Is there a way to ensure the command `apt-update` runs before my MySQL module?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/4600205) you can find my current default.pp manifest for my

I've tried various ways to make sure apt-update command is executed first but nothing seems to work. At line 148 I tried the following code,

`package { 'mysql':
    ensure => "installed",
    require => Exec['apt-update'],
  }`

But this didn't solve my issue.

Running out of ideas on how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure apt-get update happened before Puppet provisioning I placed the following command in my Vagrantfile before I defined Puppet.

`config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"`

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as dropping the quotes around "installed" or you may need to ensure latest to get mysql to update if it is already installed:

```
package { 'mysql': 
  ensure  => latest, 
  require => Exec['apt-update'], 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the execution order in puppet. If you use the puppet mysql module it comes with different classes. These are (right now):

```
**Public classes**
mysql::server: Installs and configures MySQL.
mysql::server::account_security: Deletes default MySQL accounts.
mysql::server::monitor: Sets up a monitoring user.
mysql::server::mysqltuner: Installs MySQL tuner script.
mysql::server::backup: Sets up MySQL backups via cron.
mysql::bindings: Installs various MySQL language bindings.
mysql::client: Installs MySQL client (for non-servers).
```

So, to set the APT module as first set the execution order of all mysql module classes you are using. For example:

```
Class['apt'] -> Class['mysql::server'] -> Class['mysql::client'] -> Class['mysql::bindings']
```

Now, all sql related stuff in your puppet script will executed after apt.